# Return json adata with relation object Laravel API

Tags: laravel, api

I'm using Laravel as my backend API management.

Function for retrieving JSON data is simple, just one function in Controller:

```
public function edit(User $manage_user){

    return response()->json([
        "success" => true,
        "message" => 'Edit user',
        "data" => $manage_user
    ], 200);
}
```

but in `User` model I have function:

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id', 'id');
}
```

now how to retrieve via API JSON option to return user data with client data?

I tried this:

```
"data" => $manage_user->with('client')->get()
```

but that return all users data with client, also tried with `first()` but than I get first user in database.

Comment: do it like `"data" => $manage_user->load(['client'])`

Comment: It works, thank you very much. I started to read documentation, but that is before and :) : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships